# Can't create Android SD card in Eclipse emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, sd-card

I'm having trouble creating an SD card for my Android emulator. I've heard that you have to use the mksdcard tool, like this:

mksdcard -l mysdcard 128M sdcard.img

However, I'm not sure where I'm supposed to type this in. I tried typing it into the console at the bottom, but it's read-only and doesn't accept input. Also, when I try to type this in the Windows command line I get an error.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.. I hope it works for you too.

- Open Android Virtual device manager
- Select your emulator
- Edit your emulator
- Specify the size of your sd card 1024MB
- In hardware option click new set property add sd card support: yes(value)
- Start your emulator, in eclipse window–>showview–>other->android–>file explorer
- In File explorer open mnt->sdcard and using pushfile button for insert your file and image
- DONE

Answer (score 2):

If you have the sdcard configured and you want to upload files to it

go to your DDMS > File Explorer > mnt > sdcard where you can push files using the cell phone with the arrow icon (eclipse)

Answer (score 2):

`mksdcard` is a tool that is included in the Android SDK under "tools". It is, however, not installed in the system path. For this reason, typing "mksdcard" in a terminal window does not work. However, you can find the directory where you installed the Android SDK, the subdirectory "tools" under it, and there you have the "mksdcard" program. Run in terminal, first change to that directory and then type the mksdcard command line.

```
 cd c:\whatever\android-sdk\tools
 mksdcard -l mylabel 128M sdcard.img
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one thing all you guys are leaving out. The mksdcard tool will not create an image on a path that is denied create permissions. You may have to check the permissions of the path you are creating the image.

You may also want to create the image to a particular path. you can do this by specifying the full path as expressed in the following example.

```
mksdcard 256M D:\MySDCard
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> from eclipse go to window>preferences then go to the android tab/list
>   item and expand it in there you will see "Launch" item, click that in
>   here you will see "emulator options" these command line switches go
>   there
>
> however when you create your device in the "Android SDK and AVD
>   Manager" the screen that comes up has an option for the size of the SD
>   card, i would try setting it in there

Comment: did any of this work?  can you please mark the question as answered or post a comment with an update